# Why is my console printing blank/same colour as background on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

so this has been troubling me for a little while. I actually thought my code wasn't working. I was using `System.out.println();` to test if I was getting the correct output but the console kept coming up blank so I had assumed it wasn't working.

After further investigation it has been working the entire time but it has been printing the text the same colour as the console making it appear blank. Any idea why?

```
    public APIRequests() {
}
public void UnirestCall(String URL) throws UnirestException {
     response = Unirest.get(URL)
            .header("x-rapidapi-host", "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
            .header("x-rapidapi-key", APIKEY)
            .asJson()
            .getBody();
     System.out.println("1" + response.toString());
    
}

public JsonNode countriesRequest() throws UnirestException {
    
    UnirestCall(APIURL.concat("countries/"));
    System.out.println("2" + response.toString());
    response = getResponse();
    return response;
}

public JsonNode getResponse() {
    return response;
}   
}
```

main method

```
import apicalls.APIRequests;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnirestException {
    
    APIRequests request = new APIRequests();
    request.countriesRequest();
    System.out.println("Test");
    System.out.println("3" + request.getResponse().toString());
}
}
```

Output in the console to the naked eye
[image: console]

When I highlight the line in the console, copy and paste to notepad, its all there.

I am sure I can't be the first person to have this problem, I just couldn't find the answer so sorry if the question already exists. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm OR https://askubuntu.com/questions/390508/how-to-change-eclipse-console-output-color

Comment: probably a bug in used theme (that's one reason why I stopped using anything but default) maybe you can change the color settings in eclipse (or the theme)

Comment: Please do not place images of text on Stack Overflow. Instead, I would ask for you to copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: I think there is a special sequence in your JSON string that is interpreted as a color change by eclipse terminal try adding some space after "3" in the second print line

Comment: It works fine today, I changed no code. It was a bug of some sort but I have no idea what caused it and why it was only the JSON.toString() System prints that it was happening to. Only thing I can suggest is if it happens to someone else restart your machine.